# When doing doing AlignSeqs using DECIPHER I am getting Error: node stack overflow Error during wrapup: node stack overflow

Tags: r

I am doing DNA sequence alignment using DECIPHER (AlignSeqs). I am getting the error in the second step (Clustering into groups by similarity:)

alignmentFls <- AlignSeqs(DNAStringSet(seqFls), processors=NULL, anchor=NA)

Determining distance matrix based on shared 7-mers:
  |===============================================================================================================================================| 100%

Time difference of 104.46 secs

Clustering into groups by similarity:
  |===============================================================================================================================================| 100%
Error: node stack overflow
Error during wrapup: node stack overflow

Does anyone know what the issue is and potential solutions?

Thanks,

Ebi

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in [DECIPHER](http://DECIPHER.codes) version 2.6. Please update your R and then reinstall DECIPHER to begin using the latest version.